# What is the meaning of "proceed"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read this sentence in the book *Revolution 2020*:

> We **proceeded** to Mughal Sarai to meet a retired chemical professor.

In this sentence, it seems like *proceeded* means "went", but I'm not sure.  When I looked up the word in a dictionary, there were several meanings listed. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/proceed), for example, lists three:

> - to continue as planned : *His lawyers have decided not to proceed with the case*.
> - to do something after you have done something else : *She sat down and proceeded to tell me about her skiing holiday*.
> - `formal` to move forward or travel in a particular direction : *Passengers for Madrid should proceed to gate 26 for boarding.*

The closest meaning seems to be the third one, but the author of the book isn't using this in a formal context, so I'm wondering if my assumptions are right.

Is this correct? Can *proceeded* be used to mean "went", even outside of a formal setting?

Comment: basic questions about 'meaning' of the words are off topic. Saravanan. You may check any dictionary and find the word's meaning in that context.

Comment: I've reopened the question after providing the requisite research. [Let this be an example](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/27420/revisions) when asking about the meaning of words. It's OK to ask about the meaning of a word once you've tried to figure it out yourself; however, you need to include your research, meaning **share what you found, and explain why you're still confused**. Such questions are welcomed here; however, if you omit that information, everyone will naturally assume you didn't bother to look it up, and you should have consulted a dictionary, not asked a new ELL question.

Comment: Thanks J.R for your kind advice. i will keep your suggetion hereafter.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is spelled as "Proceed" and the past tense is "Proceeded" which means "to go on" or "to continue".

As [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proceed) says:

> **proceed** (*v.*) to advance or carry on, esp after stopping

So, in the sentence you quote:

> We procedded to Mughal Sarai to meet a retired chemical professor

it sounds like a group of people are on some kind of journey or adventure, and the next step of the trek was to travel to Mughal Sarai.

Comment: Since I've improved the question, I may as well improve this answer, which had already been flagged and downvoted. Answers should carry some measure of authority. A sentence like: _"Proceed" means "to go on" or "to continue"_ reads more like an opinion; it's best to elaborate a little bit. Questions about word meaning often include excerpts from online dictionaries, to substantiate and/or explain the word's meaning.